# ContentPane background color changes when adding object

Tags: java, swing

I have the following code:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
public class Ball extends JPanel implements Runnable {

    List<Ball> balls = new ArrayList<Ball>();   
    Color color;
    int diameter;
    long delay;
    private int x;
    private int y;
    private int vx;
    private int vy;

    public Ball(String ballcolor, int xvelocity, int yvelocity) {
        color = Color.PINK;
        diameter = 30;
        delay = 40;
        x = 1;
        y = 1;
        vx = xvelocity;
        vy = yvelocity;
    }

    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D)g;
        g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
        g.setColor(color);
        g.fillOval(x,y,50,50); //adds color to circle
        g.setColor(Color.pink);
        g2.drawOval(x,y,50,50); //draws circle
    }

    public void run() {
        while(isVisible()) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(delay);
            } catch(InterruptedException e) {
                System.out.println("interrupted");
            }
            move();
            repaint();
        }
    }

    public void move() {
        if(x + vx < 0 || x + diameter + vx > getWidth()) {
            vx *= -1;
        }
        if(y + vy < 0 || y + diameter + vy > getHeight()) {
            vy *= -1;
        }
        x += vx;
        y += vy;
    }

    private void start() {
        while(!isVisible()) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(25);
            } catch(InterruptedException e) {
                System.exit(1);
            }
        }
        Thread thread = new Thread(this);
        thread.setPriority(Thread.NORM_PRIORITY);
        thread.start();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Ball ball1 = new Ball("pink",6,6);
        JFrame f = new JFrame();
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        f.getContentPane().add(ball1);
        f.setSize(1000,500);
        f.setLocation(200,200);
        new Thread(ball1).start();
        f.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

I would like to make the background black instead of the default grey one, but this only works if I get the ball out of the code, basically deleting `f.getContentPane().add(ball1);`. What I want is a pink ball bouncing on a black background, but it keeps going back to grey when adding the ball.

What is the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Ball` which extends from `JPanel` is opaque (not see through), so it is filling it's own background with it's default color...

You could make `Ball` transparent by using `setOpaque(false)` or set the `Ball`'s background color to `BLACK` using `setBackground(Color.BLACK)` for example...

ps- I should add, because `JFrame` uses a `BorderLayout`, your `Ball` pane will occupy the entire available space within the center of the frame (`CENTER` being the default position and the frame not containing any other components)